# Translating Cygwin path to Windows

Tags: vim, cygwin, cygpath

HI, 
I have cygwin installed in my Windows system. 
I have written two function in my profile file so that every time I open vi/vim, it will open with gvim.

But with this one of the issue, the windows path and Cygwin path. I tried with Cygpath as below:

```
function vi () 
{ 
    win_file_path=$(cygpath -w $*)
    gvim "$win_file_path" & 
}
```

Bu with this, when ever I open a file like this: "`vi /etc/exports +5`", it will result in error. So let me know if any of you have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the file arguments only:

```
function vi ()  
{   
    local -a viargs
    local a
    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
    do
        a="$1"
        if [ -e "$a" ]; then a="$(cygpath -w "$a")"; fi
        viargs[${#viargs[@]}]="$a"
        shift
    done
    gvim "${viargs[@]}" &  
}
```

Instead of being 'smart' about existing files like this, feel free to simplify to treat just the first argument :)

In recent bash versions you can replace the ugly line

```
        viargs[${#viargs[@]}]="$a"
```

with

```
        viargs+=( "$a" )
```

Answer (score 1):

[cyg-wrapper](http://hermitte.free.fr/cygwin/#Win32) has been written for this sole purpose.

NB: See also the related [wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Running_the_win32-version_of_Vim_from_cygwin).